# передать данные от компонента к компоненту react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть код на react, который использует два независимых компонента. При нажатии на кнопку в первом компоненте я скрываю текущий компонент и отображаю другой компонент. Но также я хочу передавать некоторые значения из первого компонента (из **INPUTS**) во второй компонент. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать? Вот код:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FirstSection} from './components/FirstSection';
import { SecondSection} from './components/SecondSection';

function App() {
  const [checkSection, setSection] = useState(false);
  const showSecondSection= () => setSection(true);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {checkSection ? <SecondSection /> : <FirstSection onClick={showSecondSection} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**FirstSection.jsx**

```
export function FirstSection({onClick}) {
    return(
        <>
         <input type="text" value="{input1}" />
         <input type="text" value="{input2}" />
         <button onClick={onClick}>Continue</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

**SecondSection.jsx**

```
export function SecondSection() {
    return(
        <>
         <p>{input1}, {input2}</p> <== Сюда я хочу передать данные из первого компонента
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FirstSection} from './components/FirstSection';
import { SecondSection} from './components/SecondSection';

function App() {
  const [checkSection, setSection] = useState(false);
  const showSecondSection= () => setSection(true);
  const [firstInput, setFirstInput] = useState("");
  const [secondInput, setSecondInput] = useState("");
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {checkSection ? 
          <SecondSection 
            firstInput={firstInput}
            secondInput={secondInput}
          /> : 
          <FirstSection 
            firstInput={firstInput}
            secondInput={secondInput}
            setFirstInput={setFirstInput}
            setSecondInput={setSecondInput}
            onClick={showSecondSection} 
          />
         }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Компонент **FirstSection**

```
export function FirstSection({onClick, firstInput, setFirstInput, secondInput, setSecondInput }) {
    return(
        <>
         <input type="text" value={firstInput} onChange={e => setFirstInput(e.target.value)}/>
         <input type="text" value={secondInput} onChange={e => setSecondInput(e.target.value)} />
         <button onClick={onClick}>Continue</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Компонент **SecondSection**

```
export function SecondSection({ firstInput, secondInput }) {
    return(
        <>
         <p>{firstInput}, {secondInput}</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

[**Playcode**](https://playcode.io/1698617)

Comment: Спасибо, друг!!!